# How to configure Pre-Domain using qtranslate (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I want ask...

I want using qtranslate plugin on my wordpress site.

i want model link url like this

`www.example.com` << default using English language

`www.ru.example.com` << using Russia language

`www.id.example.com` << using Indonesia language

Image > You can open this [link](https://scontent-a-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10485796_323458217858815_1898257094089346115_n.jpg?oh=12674ac99b3b60f8dec742485d2e2ae0&oe=54D5CD46)

Pre-Path and Pre-Domain mode will only work with `mod_rewrite`/`pretty permalinks`. Additional Configuration is needed for Pre-Domain mode!

I don't know where i configure this, 
i confused, i don't find search in Google...
Please Help me..